# Sharepoint List Additional

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I am using SharePoint online.

I have a list that I would like one of my teams to action, when they action I would like this list to be added on (further fields are displayed) and then 2nd team can add more info

Example

This is for any agent to fill out

[image]

Then i would like it submitted to a Process Team who add extra info
[image]

---

This could be completed in one list and a message saying for new tasks "fill to Operations line"

however may be slightly confusing and unnecessary 
Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by added on? adding entries or columns?

Comment: one list combined with another or fields added on

Comment: Can you please update your question with an example?

Comment: example added, let me know if i can clarify on anything

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible in SharePoint. Best way to achieve this OOB will be to create 2 content types.

1. For Agent (add columns which agent has to fill in this content type)
2. For process team (add columns which the team has to fill in this content type)

Add both these content types to your list and make Agent content type as default content type for the list. Then when you click on "add item" in the list, the form for agent will open. Agent fills form and submits. Process team can view this as item in the list and click on edit. Same form (agent form) will open up. Here, there will be 1 more field called **Content Type** which will have 2 options of both forms. Click on Project Team form option and the additional fields will be displayed on the form. Fill and submit.

Another way would be to modify the form using PowerApps.
Hope this resolves. Let me know if I can help more.